# Passing **kwargs to function results in `Unexpected keyword argument` in flask app, but not test script

Tags: python, flask

I'm getting an unexpected keyword argument in my flask app. When I execute the same functions in a test python file, I don't get the `TypeError`.

In my flask app, I have a worker class and a function:

```
import concurrent.futures as cf


class Worker:
    """Class for multiprocessing."""

    def __init__(self, workers=1):
        self.workers = workers

    def run(self, fn, files, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs)
        num = len(files)
        with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=self.workers) as executor:
            results = [executor.submit(fn, f, **kwargs) for f in files]
            for i, f in enumerate(cf.as_completed(results), start=1):
                print(f'({i}/{num}): {f.result()}')
```

```
def create_archive(folder, extension='.tar.gz', format='PAX', remove_directory=False):
   # do some stuff
```

I execute the `run` method `Worker` like this in one of the routes:

```
    worker = Worker(workers=5)

    worker.run(
        create_archive,
        valid_folders,
        extension=request.json['extension'],
        format=request.json['format'],
        remove_directory=str2bool(request.json['removeDir'])
    )
```

and get this error message:

```
TypeError: create_archive() got an unexpected keyword argument 'extension'
```

The `print` statement in the `run` methods produces this output:

```
{'extension': '.tar.gz', 'format': 'pax', 'remove_directory': False}
```

Now, I created a separate `test.py` script to try and replicate the issue. I get the same output from the print statement, and the code executes properly. Here's the `test.py`:

```
import concurrent.futures as cf


class Worker:
    """Class for multiprocessing."""

    def __init__(self, workers=1):
        self.workers = workers

    def run(self, fn, files, **kwargs):
        print(kwargs)
        num = len(files)
        with cf.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=self.workers) as executor:
            results = [executor.submit(fn, f, **kwargs) for f in files]
            for i, f in enumerate(cf.as_completed(results), start=1):
                print(f'({i}/{num}): {f.result()}')


def create_archive(folder, extension='.tar.gz', format='pax', remove_directory=False):
    print(folder, extension, format, remove_directory)
    return f'{folder} complete'


if __name__ == "__main__":

    worker = Worker(workers=5)
    worker.run(
        create_archive,
        ['folder 1', 'folder 2', 'folder 3'],
        extension='.tar',
        format='pax',
        remove_directory=False
    )
```

I've been looking at this for a long time and I don't see what the issue is. Any ideas as to why I'm getting this error in my flask app but not the test script?

Full error message:

```
concurrent.futures.process._RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/useridhere/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/process.py", line 256, in _process_worker
    r = call_item.fn(*call_item.args, **call_item.kwargs)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: create_archive() got an unexpected keyword argument 'extension'
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/useridhere/repos/myproject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1478, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/useridhere/repos/myproject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 43, in __call__
    return super(_SocketIOMiddleware, self).__call__(environ,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/useridhere/repos/myproject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/engineio/middleware.py", line 74, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/useridhere/repos/myproject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1458, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/useridhere/repos/myproject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 176, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/useridhere/repos/myproject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1455, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/useridhere/repos/myproject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 869, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/useridhere/repos/myproject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask_cors/extension.py", line 176, in wrapped_function
    return cors_after_request(app.make_response(f(*args, **kwargs)))
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/useridhere/repos/myproject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 867, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/useridhere/repos/myproject/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 852, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/useridhere/repos/myproject/app.py", line 93, in create_archive
    worker.run(
  File "/Users/useridhere/repos/myproject/api/utilities.py", line 13, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/useridhere/repos/myproject/api/worker.py", line 18, in run
    print(f'({i}/{num}): {f.result()}')
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/useridhere/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 449, in result
    return self.__get_result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/useridhere/miniconda3/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 401, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
TypeError: create_archive() got an unexpected keyword argument 'extension'
```

Flask app:

*app.py* (the `request.json` parameters are strings, the values aren't important because of the error message I'm getting)

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from flask import jsonify, request

from entry import app, app_config, socketio
from api.worker import Worker
from api.utilities import str2bool
from api.archives import create_archive


@socketio.on('create-logger', namespace='/archive')
@socketio.on('create-progress', namespace='/archive')
@app.route('/archive/create', methods=['POST'])
def create_archive():

    if not request.json['items']:
        return jsonify({
            'status': 500,
            'message': 'No folders were provided.',
            'invalid': []
        })

    # Confirm items are folders and not files
    invalid_folders = []
    for folder in request.json['items']:
        folder_path = folder['path']
        if not os.path.isdir(folder_path):
            invalid_folders.append(folder_path)

    if invalid_folders:
        return jsonify({
            'status': 500,
            'message': 'All items provided must be folders. Open the developer tools to see a list of the invalid items.',
            'invalid': invalid_folders
        })

    folders = [folder['path'] for folder in request.json['items']]

    valid_folders = []
    existing_archives = []
    for folder in folders:
        archive_filename = os.path.join(Path(folder).parent, Path(
            folder).name + request.json['extension'])

        if os.path.isfile(archive_filename):
            existing_archives.append(archive_filename)
        else:
            valid_folders.append(folder)

    socketio.emit('create-logger', 'Creating archive file(s)...',
                  namespace='/archive')

    worker = Worker(workers=5)

    worker.run(
        create_archive,
        valid_folders,
        extension=request.json['extension'],
        format=request.json['format'],
        remove_directory=str2bool(request.json['removeDir'])
    )

    socketio.emit('create-logger', 'Archiving complete',
                  namespace='/archive')

    return jsonify({
        'status': 200,
        'message': 'Archiving complete.',
        'exists': existing_archives
    })


if __name__ == "__main__":
    socketio.run(app, **app_config)
```

*entry.py*

```
import sys
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_socketio import SocketIO


app = Flask(__name__)
app_config = {"port": sys.argv[1]}

# Developer mode uses app.py
if "app.py" in sys.argv[0]:
    # Update app config
    app_config["debug"] = True

    # CORS settings
    cors = CORS(
        app,
        resources={r"/*": {"origins": "http://localhost*"}},
    )

    # CORS headers
    app.config["CORS_HEADERS"] = "Content-Type"

socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins='*')
```

*archives.py*

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '..')

import os  # NOQA
import tarfile  # NOQA
import fnmatch  # NOQA
import shutil  # NOQA
from pathlib import Path  # NOQA

from entry import socketio  # NOQA
from api.utilities import winapi_path  # NOQA


def create_archive(folder, extension='.tar.gz', format='PAX', remove_directory=False):
    """Create an archive file.

    Parameters
    ----------
    folder : str, path-like object
        Name of the folder to archive.

    extension : str, '.tar' or '.tar.gz' (default)
        File extension for archive file.

    format : str, 'PAX' (default) or 'GNU'
        Archive file format.

    remove_directory : bool, default is False
        Option to remove folder after the archive file is created.

    Returns
    -------
    dict
        Info containing filename and the total files included in the
        archive file.
    """
    socketio.emit('create-logger',
                  f'Creating archive for {folder}', namespace='/archive')

    # Build filename
    filename = os.path.join(Path(folder).parent, Path(folder).name + extension)

    # Initalize info
    info = {'filename': filename, 'total_files': 0}

    # Determine mode
    mode = 'x:' if extension.lower() == '.tar' else 'x:gz'

    # Set format
    fmt = tarfile.GNU_FORMAT if format.lower() == 'gnu' else tarfile.PAX_FORMAT

    with tarfile.open(filename, mode=mode, format=fmt) as tar:
        for dirpath, _, filenames in os.walk(folder):
            if filenames:
                for file in filenames:
                    path = Path(os.path.join(dirpath, file))

                    # arcname provides an alternate name that is relative
                    # to the folder being archived
                    altname = path.relative_to(Path(folder).parent)

                    # Enable long path
                    path = winapi_path(str(path))

                    tar.add(path, recursive=False, arcname=altname)

                    info['total_files'] += 1

    if remove_directory:
        shutil.rmtree(folder)

    socketio.emit('create-progress', 1, namespace='/archive')

    return info
```

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Flask, but you should probably post the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341)

Comment: Plz provide the entire error message and what exactly is extension=request.json['extension'] in your worker.run() ?

Comment: Could you also provide the complete code of your flask app? It seems like a typo somewhere, because your snippets look just fine

Comment: @tetrisprogramming I added the full error message. The request.json['extension'] is just a string determining the extension (e.g., .tar, .gz, etc). What the value of that is isn't relevant because of the `extension` argument isn't being recognized.

Comment: @Ralubrusto I added the relevant portions of the flask app. I left out a couple of the utility functions that I import because those aren't really relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally figured it out. My issue was because my route name was `create_archive` and my function name was called `create_archive`. Changing the name of my route fixed my issue.

*Old*

```
@app.route('/archive/create', methods=['POST'])
def create_archive():
...
```

*New*

```
@app.route('/archive/create', methods=['POST'])
def archive_create():
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In your app.py you use the function/route name `creat_archive` twice

1. `from api.archives import create_archive`
2. `def create_archive()`:

The 1)create_archive from your api.archives takes parameters like extension... The 2) create_archive takes no parameters and overwrites 1) because the `def create_archive()` is called after the import.

This results in the error because the now active create_archive() cannot take any parameters.

To solve this you need to rename one of these 2 same named functions.